# Function throws Compile Error: Can't Find Project or Library on Dim lines

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

According to my peers this macro once worked in pasting numbers onto PDFs from a query in access. Just a guess but I am assuming since COVID-19 with everyone being home and that being the time this macro stopped working maybe this could be an issue of being on the wireless serves. I'm no expert but if that seems right and you know maybe I can bring it up.

When running this macro, which is the printing section of the macro (pasting PO numbers onto a PDF Invoice) this error seems to come up. Again, 2 months ago this worked fine. Any ideas what could be the issue? Nothing has changed in this macro from when it worked to now. The error message reads "**Compile Error: Can't Find Project or Library**" and it highlights the first line in yellow and highlights the 3rd line as well.

```
Private Function Print2PDF(FileName As String, Path As String) As String
Dim oSheet As Worksheet
Dim oPDF As PdfDistiller
Dim TmpPSFile As String
Dim PDFFile As String
Set oSheet = ActiveSheet
Set oPDF = New PdfDistiller

TmpPSFile = Path & "TmpPSFile.ps"
Path = Path & FileName & ".pdf"
PDFFile = Path

oSheet.PrintOut copies:=1, preview:=False, _
ActivePrinter:="Acrobat Distiller", printtofile:=True, _
collate:=True, PrToFileName:=TmpPSFile
oPDF.FileToPDF TmpPSFile, PDFFile, ""
Kill TmpPSFile
Print2PDF = Path

End Function
```

Has anyone used a macro in a similar way that could help me find out what the issue could be?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Did `PdfDistiller` get uninstalled/removed? Has it been added to the project references?

Comment: Im sorry, this is Excel!

Comment: Go to the VBA project references and see if anything is tagged as "missing"

Comment: @TimWilliams it looks like there are 4 sheets in there all of which are blank. There is one sheet to paste what I have from Access and then an output sheet but both look blank

Comment: In the Excel VBA editor (Alt+F11) select *Tools >> References*   Is anything there tagged as "missing" ?

Comment: It will not let me select references in here.

Comment: Make sure the code is stopped (ie you're not in Break mode)

Comment: Missing: Acorbat Distiller

Comment: Missing: Adobe Acorbat 10.0 Type Library

Comment: I guess then you don't have those installed and/or registered (see first comment above).